# What does "sink and copper" mean in British parlance circa 1937?

Tags: vocabulary, british-english, literature

Near the start of Chapter IV of "*The Road to Wigan Pier*" (1937), Orwell in describing the typical living conditions for coal miners states (**my emphasis**):

> *All have an almost exactly similar living-room, ten or fifteen feet square, with an open kitchen range; in the larger ones there is a scullery as well, in the smaller ones **the sink and copper** are in the living room.*

What does Orwell mean by '*copper*' in the phrase "*the sink and copper*" in this context?

Comment: A "copper" was typically a large metal tank of upright cylindrical shape, used for heating sufficient hot water for a bath or some task that required a large quantity of water. Once heated, the water was drained into the bathtub, sink or whatever. They were very common in British homes up until the advent of central-heating systems or 'back-boilers' and other systems. I recall that my parents had a gas-powered boiler that was kept in the scullery. It was pulled out on bath-days and connected to an adjacent gas tap on the wall in the bathroom!

Comment: @BillJ: Thanks Bill. Would you care to make that an answer?

Comment: I apologize for the irascibility of my answer (since deleted). It was the product of a frustrating day compounded by the previous night's insomnia which looked to be repeating. And while that is not an excuse, I hope you'll take the situation into consideration. Thanks to @WS2 for pointing out the answer's inaccuracy as well, and I encourage him to post his own. I have rescinded my close vote, and I commend you for your explorations into literature and language, passions I share with you.

Comment: @Robusto: Accepted - I have been there myself at times. It's now all water under the bridge, and behind us.

Comment: @BillJ: As a stop-gap, I have posted your comment above as an answer pending a complete answer either by yourself or someone else.

Answer (score 4):

Comments being ephemeral, I am posting the (partial-answer) comment above, by [@BillJ](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/141248/billj), pending a more complete one either by himself or someone else:

> A "copper" was typically a large metal tank of upright cylindrical shape, used for heating sufficient hot water for a bath or some task that required a large quantity of water. Once heated, the water was drained into the bathtub, sink or whatever. They were very common in British homes up until the advent of central-heating systems or 'back-boilers' and other systems.
>
> I recall that my parents had a gas-powered boiler that was kept in the scullery. It was pulled out on bath-days and connected to an adjacent gas tap on the wall in the bathroom!

---

So, a *copper* seems to be (a small equivalent of) what in Canada today is referred to as "*the hot water tank*"; and which is usually situated in the basement of Canadian houses but might be located on the main floor of a ranch-style house or condominium. However, from the personal comment quoted above by @BillJ it seems that this object might occasionally be [a chattel rather than a fixture](https://www.century21.ca/Blog/Will_It_Stay_Chattel_vs_Fixture). In contrast, a *sink* would always be a fixture, the chattel equivalent being a *wash basin* or *wash stand*.

As I read further through *The Road to Wigan Pier* it becomes evident that Orwell is consistently very precise and exact in his phrasing and use of words. This gives credence, in my eyes, for the validity of drawing the distinction above.

---

[Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wash_copper) is the *laundry copper* referred to below [@BoldBen](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/191850/boldben), with his comment text
[image]

> The point is that the "wash copper" was heated by its own solid fuel fire with its own chimney and was not a hot water tank like the one you describe. As Orwell mentions other houses having a scullery I believe that he meant the dedicated wash copper.

Comment: In the house I grew up in (built in 1928) there was a "wash house" containing a _copper_ very like the one illustrated in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wash_copper). My mother had a washing machine so did not use the copper but I know that other people at the time did use them. The point is that the "wash copper" was heated by its own solid fuel fire with its own chimney and was not a hot water tank like the one you describe. As Orwell mentions other houses having a scullery I believe that he meant the dedicated wash copper.

Comment: @BoldBen: Excellent. Would you care to make that an answer?